# high pitched car whine

Tags: noise, car

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pB-CyATT-tY&feature=youtu.be

can't figure out what this noise is. took it to the mechanic twice and they couldn't hear anything. there's a high pitched noise coming from the car that you can clearly hear in the video. any idea what this is?

about car: 2014 honda civic CVT with 25,000

last time i took the car to the mechanic they said the idler pulley, belt and tensioner looked OK. not sure what that means.

Comment: If you turn the wheel back and forth does the sound change?

Comment: no it doesn't. neither does driving it

Answer (score 0):

Take a meter-long piece of heater hose or garden hose, and hold one end against your ear. Use the other end like a stethoscope and carefully place it near various pulleys, belts, air intakes and exhaust.
Be careful near the fan and hot exhaust. You can put a small funnel into the hose end toward the engine if you like. When you find the location, get advice or edit question if needed..

Comment: can you hear the noise or nah?

Comment: I only hear rumbling, tapping, and mic noise. But if you hear it, track it down and let us know the location.

Comment: at the end of the vid it gets extra loud. its kind of subtle. its like a very high pitched whistle noise almost. i wonder if its just too high frequency for some ppl to hear it?

Comment: Find the source.

Comment: i can not hear the whining sound,i guess it might be the aternator that have bad bearings,it might be the waterpump too the seals do dry out and do often make a high pitch noise before it fails.